# Doesn't respond when web crawling in python

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I want to get a list of golden-cross. So

[image: all]

I found that its id value is #contentarea_right.
Along the subindex, I wrote the following code

[image: sub index]

```
a_list = soup.select("#contentarea_right > div#box_type_r > table#trend_tab_1 > tbody > tr > td a")
or
a_list = soup.select("#contentarea_right > div > table#trend_tab_1 > tbody > tr > td a")
or
a_list = soup.select("#contentarea_right > div > tbody > tr > td a")
or
a_list = soup.select("#contentarea_right > div > table > tbody > tr > td a")
```

But nothing happens... How to fix?

Full code

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as req
url = "https://finance.naver.com/sise/"
res = req.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
#contentarea_right > div
a_list = soup.select("#contentarea_right > div#box_type_r > table#trend_tab_1 > tbody > tr > td a")
for a in a_list:
    name = a.string
    print("-",name)
```

Comment: often `HTML` doesn't have tag `<tbody>` but browser always show it in tree. Try without `tbody`

Comment: maybe reduce selection to something shorter. Works for me `"#contentarea_right #trend_tab_1 a"`

Answer (score 0):

If I use shorter selector

```
"#contentarea_right #trend_tab_1 a"
```

then I get some data

---

Example with different selector

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as req

url = "https://finance.naver.com/sise/"
res = req.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")

rows = soup.select("#contentarea_right #trend_tab_1 tr")
for row in rows:
    cols = row.select('td')
    print("-", cols[0].text, '|', cols[1].text)
```

Result

```
- 청호컴넷 | 3,685
- 한진 | 36,950
- 모다이노칩 | 3,500
- 인터로조 | 28,000
- 티피씨글로벌 | 2,650
- 서연탑메탈 | 2,900
- 아이앤씨 | 5,250
- 바른손 | 2,095
- 한글과컴퓨터 | 10,700
- 금강공업우 | 8,890
```

Answer (score 0):

`box_type_r` is a class, not an id, and there is no `tbody` in that table. `tbody` you see in inspector was probably automatically generated by your web browser. Change your CSS selector to the following.

`soup.select("#contentarea_right > div.box_type_r > table#trend_tab_1 > tr > td a")`